# Replace whitespace in array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have an index page that takes a user input list of items separated by a space. It processes that list as an array and replaces the white space with a ", ". However, my PHP script doesn't seem to do that and I'm not sure I understand why.

**index.php**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <b>Enter a list of items separated by a space:</b> <br><input name="list[]" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$list = $_POST["list"];
$list = preg_replace('#\s+#',', ',trim($list));
echo "<b>Your listed items were:</b> $list";

?>
```

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**
Thanks a lot everyone! Seems like my issue was a fairly novice one and fixing it was pretty easy.

Comment: `$list` is an array of inputs. Process it as an array

Comment: Use `$list = explode(' ', $list);` That will make it an array. Then, you can loop through the array posting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're running preg_replace on an array.

Instead, try use `array_walk`:

```
$list = array('this', 'is a', 'test');

array_walk($list, function(&$v){
    $v = str_replace(' ', ', ', trim($v));
});


print_r(implode(', ', $list));

// Outputs: this, is, a, test

print_r(explode(', ', implode(', ', $list)));

// Outputs: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Alternatively, if you want to do the same for a string:

```
$string = 'This is some test string';

print_r(str_replace(' ', ', ', trim($string)));
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove [] from input name:

**index.php**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <b>Enter a list of items separated by a space:</b> <br><input name="list" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

2. Do you really need regular expressions here? Use [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) as it is more efficient:

**process.php**

```
<?php
$list = $_POST["list"];
$list = strtr(trim($list), ' ', ',');
echo "<b>Your listed items were:</b> $list";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you set the input name to `list[]` which is submitted to the server side script as an array. To process, you have two options:

1. Change the input type to `<input name="list" type="text">`, and leave the server side script as you currently have it. Notice the "list" has no braces `[]` after it.
2. Leave the front end HTML as you currently have it and update your server side code thus:

   ```
   $lists = $_POST["list"]; //this comes in as an array from the HTML form
   $str = '';
   foreach($lists AS $list)
   {
       $str .= preg_replace('#\s+#',', ',trim($list));
   }
   echo "<b>Your listed items were:</b> $str";
   ```

Comment: This definitely makes a little bit more sense. Is it bad practice to use preg_replace on an array?

Comment: If you have to use `preg_replace` on an array, then you have to use it with one `array_walk_*` family of functions. As `preg_replace` usually works with string parameters.